# Gulp errors and IntelliJ/WebStorm integration

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp, webstorm

I'm trying to figure out how to output errors from gulp in such a way that the WebStorm/IntelliJ task runner is able to first recognize that the line indicates an error and second is able to jump you to the relevant file, line, and column (or even better, highlight the text range somehow), when the error line is clicked on.

Visual Studio Code allows for custom "Problem Matchers" which provide this functionality (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks).

Does gulp itself have a standard format for indicating this to IDE's?

Comment: Well ... IDE should be recognizing any standard FILENAME:LINENUMBER and convert them into clickable links. I'm not using Gulp myself, so not 100% sure how it works .. but most of stuff (e.g. External Tools/File Watchers etc) allow you to specify such patterns (look for "Output filters").  In any case: try Awesome Console plugin -- maybe it will work with Gulp output window as well. As for indicating errors -- Grep Console plugin -- it can highlight whole lines/text based on text/pattern - enough for me to spot the execution result.

Comment: I finally got the chance to try Awesome Console and while I like it enough to keep it it does not integrate with the task runner output.  I'll keep Grep Console in mind for future also.